# Formula and text combined within VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am having an issue with combining a formula with text in the VBA format. Can anyone hel :) The line of my code which errors with a 1004 error is;

```
Range("D4").Value = "=Control Page'!$M$9&" Cost Challenge FTE Tracker by Month"
```

I would like to pick up the values within Worksheet Controlpage'!$M$9 and combine it with the text Cost Challenge FTE Tracker by Month.

I am sure this should be a simple fix.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Range("D4").Formula = "='Control Page'!$M$9 & " & """ Cost Challenge FTE Tracker by Month"""
```